# jquery / (live / on@>1.7) / setTimeout / reload / ajax / contains assets (clickable)

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout, reload, clickable

a question, I use jquery to automatically reload every 5 seconces a remote php page. No problem.
This page contains assets (clickable), and I can not make it work. the element appears inactive. I said that I want to use  for another jquery fontion.

Index.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>CPAC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<a title="" style="padding : 1px 2px;" href="#"  class="cl"><img src="images/fastcoin.png"></a>
        <div id="lWorkers">Loading ...</div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    var interval = 5000;   
                    var refresh = function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "lWorkers.php",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data) {
                                $( "div#lWorkers" ).html(data);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    refresh();
                                }, interval);
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    refresh();          

                    $(".cl").click(function() {
                    alert( "toto" );
                    return false;
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And lWorkers.php sample return :

```
<a title="" style="padding : 1px 2px;" href="#"  class="cl"><img src="images/fastcoin.png"></a>
<a title="" style="padding : 1px 2px;" href="#"  class="cl"><img src="images/fastcoin.png"></a>
<a title="" style="padding : 1px 2px;" href="#"  class="cl"><img src="images/fastcoin.png"></a>
<a title="" style="padding : 1px 2px;" href="#"  class="cl"><img src="images/fastcoin.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.c1`s that you're adding via ajax *don't exist yet* when you bind the click handlers. You do the binding as soon as the document is ready but those elements are loaded later. Best bet is to use [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). Jquery makes it easy with its [`on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$( "div#lWorkers" ).on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert('toto');
});
```

The other option is to do the click binding in the `success()` callback of your `refresh` function, after you've appended the HTML to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(".cl").click(function() {
                alert( "toto" );
                return false;
                });
```

To:

```
$("body").on("click", ".cl", function() {
                alert( "toto" );
                return false;
                });
```

.click doesn't work after Ajax content refresh. "On" does.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[jQuery's .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function...